# What is your experience using Hyperic HQ to monitor a distributed/clustered systems

Tags: monitoring, java, hyperic, hyperichq

I've been trying to find a good solution (that can run on Windows) for monitoring/trending/alarming a distributed system comprised of primarly Java technology (Tomcat, ActiveMQ, JBossCache, etc.), but also some .Net and MySQL/SQLServer.  [Hyperic HQ](http://www.hyperic.com/) ([open source version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hyperic-hq/)) seems like a reasonable solution, although it doesn't support the latest version of Active MQ (5.2) or MySQL (5.1).  I was wondering what sort of experiences others have had.  Any advice, war stories, or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.

As an aside, the company I work for has adopted for general perpose monitoring [ELM](http://www.tntsoftware.com/products/ELMEnterpriseManager.aspx) from [TNT Software](http://www.tntsoftware.com/).  It has many nice features, especially when it comes to centralized logging and process monitoring.  However, it lacks specific detailed metrics and monitoring that Hyperic HQ can provide for many of the services that we use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found hyperic hq to be a very nice tool, though it is rather tough on hardware requirements. (The database backing HQ grows really fast, but then again, functionallity comes at a price).

We've once monitored a wole lot of JBoss application servers (around 300 of them) using HQ. The nice thing was that we were able to customize the JBoss plugin to match the -rather special- deployments we had.

I'd say it is a good monitoring tool which allows you really to dig into details if you have sufficient resources to run it. Its auto-discovery is really nice as well... .

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've been evaluating it for a few days and like it so far.  The only problem I've found is that it doesn't currently support ActiveMQ 5.2 (latest) or MySQL 5.1 (latest).  I think I can hack around that issue until they release a patch.

Answer (score 1):

We have liked using Hyperic (using for the past few months).

Biggest issues with hyperic:

1. I haven't been able to find a contractor to help with customization and advanced config stuff
2. They are slow to support new versions of things (like SQL Server 2008... out for a year before they have a plugin for it...)
3. Docs for advanced stuff have weak spots.
4. Forum support is spotty to get useful answers